# Why is "<?" no longer working and instead only "<?php" works?

Tags: php, xampp

I was using [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) to develop locally and then I installed the PHP from the direct installer. Now in some of my PHP code, only PHP code that starts with `"<?php`" is correctly parsed. Anything that starts with "`<?`" or "`<?=`" is completely ignored and just left as is.

How can I adjust the configuration to parse either tokens?

Comment: you shouldn't use them anyway since they break xml declarations

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a php.ini setting named

```
short_open_tag = 1 # (enabled)
```

Comment: Yes I know, but which settings?

Answer (score 20):

I recommend you to disable [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) and only work with `<?php`. When `short_open_tag` is enabled, it can collide with the [XML processing instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi) `<?xml` as both the PHP open tag and XML PI start with a `<?`.

Comment: You can sidestep it by doing this: <? echo "<?xml.."; ?>

Answer (score 3):

By using only **<?** as start preprocessor startup, you can get the preprocessor confused with well formed XML documents. XML stands **<?** for *processing-instruction*, imagine an XHTML document with embeded XML that requires XSLT processing... The preprocessor will get confused with the stylesheet processing instruction and will throw an error.

It's higly recomended to use the **<?php** processor starting tag, try using the 
short_open_tag = Off in your php.ini. Also, you can try using `<?php ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On'); >` if you are getting problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can set short_open_tag = On in the php.ini

Answer (score 1):

It's a configuration option, more information on: http://www.php.net/ini.core  (look for short_open_tag).

Answer (score 0):

For the newer version:

```
short_open_tag = On
```