# PHP works with <?php ?> and not with <? ?>

Tags: php

For some reason it seems to be working fine, only when I used `<?php ?>` tag.  Does not work with `<? ?>`

What's wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "<?" no longer working and instead only "<?php" works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435705/why-is-no-longer-working-and-instead-only-php-works)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enable short_open_tag in php.ini or enable Php short open tags in php settings in wamp (In windows)...

Answer (score 5):

Nothing's wrong. And RC quoted the wrong [option](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).. it's `short_open_tag` that you're interested in. This is why people advise against using short tags, because you run into problems like this when you try switching servers.

---

Before you guys go and horribly miscontrue my "nothing's wrong" statement, I mean that it's not a bug or defect... you're just not using the correct settings.

Comment: I used to use the <? ?> but for some reason, it does not work now, which makes me ponder, the php.ini settings have not been changed

Comment: @Jean: Well, *something* must have changed. You can dynamically change the settings with ini_set http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php as well, y'know.

Comment: Editing ini settings is not any problem. ini settings are intended for that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [php.ini setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) (short_open_tag: boolean, default: "1") to enable the use of `<? ?>`

Comment: No, that enables <% and %>. For <? you'll need short_open_tag php.ini directive.

Comment: +1 for fix. not quite sure why you thought `asp_tags` was correct though.

Comment: @Mark, just an error probably due to multi-tasking ;)
Thanks.