# Php Variable Using ?

Tags: php

I define site url with this code,

`$siteHTTPURL="http://www.example.com";`

And I want to use this variable this code in index.php;

`<a href="<?=$siteHTTPURL?>/folder1/test.php">Test >></a>`

But, this code appear status bar of the web browser..

`"<?=$siteHTTPURL?>/folder1/test.php"`

Why, `"<?=$siteHTTPURL?>"` code is not show `"http://www.example.com"` value ?

Sorry My bad English?

Comment: You do not have `short_open_tag` enabled. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941541/php-works-with-php-and-not-with/2941615#2941615

Comment: And [the epic discussion about short open tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael stated in the comments, check to see if you have short tags enabled.

Alternate syntax:

```
<a href="<?php echo $siteHTTPURL; ?>/folder1/test.php">Test >></a>
```

or

```
echo '<a href="' . $siteHTTPURL . '/folder1/test.php">Test >></a>';
```