# Syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\febi\application\views\agenda_right.php on line 22

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax-error

```
<li class="last">
            <h2>Info Penerimaan Mahasiswa Baru 2012/2013</h2>
            <div class="imgholder"><img src="<?php echo base_url().'images/'; ?>0708111913_maba.jpg" alt="mahasiswa baru" style="width:240px;height:130px;" /></div>
            <?php
                                if ($ag_2->num_rows() == 0)
                                {
                                        echo "Tidak ada agenda";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                $row = $ag_2->row();
                                $texts = $row->texts;
                                $postname = $row->postname;
                                echo word_limiter ($texts, 30);
                        ?>
                        <p class="readmore"><a href="<?php echo base_url().index_page().'/post/read/'.$postname; ?>">Baca selengkapnya &raquo;</a></p>
                        <?
                        }?>
                        </li>
        </ul>
        <br class="clear" />
    </div>
```

Comment: I think your `img` tag might be messed up

Comment: "Unexpected end of file" is usually one or more missing braces. In this instance it's probably because the server has `short_open_tag` disabled and you need to write `<?php } ?>` instead of just `<? } ?>`

Comment: try `<img src="<?php echo base_url().'images/0708111913_maba.jpg' ?>" alt="mahasiswa baru" style="width:240px;height:130px;" />`

Comment: short tags enabled? just before end of list element <?}?>

Comment: @Blaine you missed a " at the end of src

Answer (score 4):

Like DaveRandom and Blaine stated, try either:

- Replacing `<?` with `<?php`
- Enabling `short_open_tag` (See [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435705/why-is-no-longer-working-and-instead-only-php-works) for doing it in XAMPP)

Comment: The emphasis should be placed on replacing `<?` with `<?php` - enabling `short_open_tag` is arguably counter-productive as it just means the code will break again when you move it somewhere else that doesn't have it enabled.

Comment: @Dustin - you are aware you just approved an edit that erroneously formats `with` as code, and removes a valid hyperlink?  http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/342324